# psycopg2 export DB to csv with column names

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm using `psycopg2` to connect to postgre DB, and to export the data into CSV file.

This is how I made the export DB to csv:

```
def export_table_to_csv(self, table, csv_path):
    sql = "COPY (SELECT * FROM %s) TO STDOUT WITH CSV DELIMITER ','" % table
    self.cur.execute(sql)

    with open(csv_path, "w") as file:
        self.cur.copy_expert(sql, file)
```

But the data is just the rows - **without the column names**.

How can I export the data **with the column names**?

P.S. I am able to print the column names:

```
sql = '''SELECT * FROM test'''
self.cur.execute(sql)
column_names = [desc[0] for desc in self.cur.description]
for i in column_names:
    print(i)
```

I want the cleanest way to do export the DB with columns name (i.e. I prefer to do this in one method, and not rename columns In retrospect).

Comment: According to [COPY docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html), you should be able to append `, HEADER True` to the end of your WITH clause. I have not tried this so I can't say if it works for sure. If that doesn't work, you could manually write the header line and then write the data in append mode (`open(csv_path, "a"`).

Answer (score 3):

As I said in my comment, you can add `HEADER` to the WITH clause of your SQL:

```
sql = "COPY (SELECT * FROM export_test) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER"
```

By default, comma delimiters are used with CSV option so you don't need to specify.

For future Questions, you should submit a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, code we can directly copy and paste and run. I was curious if this would work so I made one and tried it:

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect('host=<host> dbname=<dbname> user=<user>')
cur = conn.cursor()

# create test table
cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS export_test')
sql = '''CREATE TABLE export_test
(
  id integer,
  uname text,
  fruit1 text,
  fruit2 text,
  fruit3 text
)'''
cur.execute(sql)

# insert data into table
sql = '''BEGIN;
insert into export_test
(id, uname, fruit1, fruit2, fruit3)
values(1, 'tom jones', 'apple', 'banana', 'pear');
insert into export_test
(id, uname, fruit1, fruit2, fruit3)
values(2, 'billy idol', 'orange', 'cherry', 'strawberry');
COMMIT;'''
cur.execute(sql)

# export to csv
fid = open('export_test.csv', 'w')
sql = "COPY (SELECT * FROM export_test) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER"
cur.copy_expert(sql, fid)
fid.close()
```

And the resultant file is:

```
id,uname,fruit1,fruit2,fruit3
1,tom jones,apple,banana,pear
2,billy idol,orange,cherry,strawberry
```