# Get column names using COPY query TO STDOUT with psycopg3

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg3

How can I get the column names when getting data using `psycopg3` with `COPY TO STDOUT` feature, f.e. `copy (select a, b, c, from t1 join t2 using (t1_id) where not t1.is_test) to STDOUT` feature? Because this is not simple select from a table, I cannot get table columns' names from metadata.

If I try to do `COPY (query) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER` (as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70598136/1828296) I get error `psycopg.DataError: bad copy format: got a newline before the end of the row`.

Another approach would be to do regular `select query limit 0` and get column names from this result, but if query is quite long/huge, this doubles amount of time/resources required to get results because I have to execute it twice.

**Please note:**

this will work well in psql, and it seems that this is not a SQL syntax issue, but rather a `psycopg3` library issue.

In their doc (psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/…) they say: *you must not specify COPY options such as FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER, NULL: please leave these details alone, thank you*. I was wondering if some workaround exists for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here [COPY](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/copy.html#copy) *Copying block-by-block*

```
with open('cp.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
    with cur.copy("COPY (select c.category, c.descript from cell_per AS cp join category AS c on cp.category = c.category where cell_per = 18) TO STDOUT WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER)") as copy:
        for data in copy:
            csv_file.write(data)

cat cp.csv
category,descript
GER SC 3.5,Scented Geraniums 3.5 in.
HERB 3.5,Herbs 3 1/2 in.
H PREM 3.5,Premium Herbs 3 1/2 inch
SUCCULENTS,Succulents
```